# Can we use ng-src to reference a local file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use ng-src to load imgs from a local folder and when I test it's returning 404 errors. Is ng-src able to reference a local folder or do you always need a hard-coded path of http://example.com/imgs/{{work.img}}.jpg?

My JSON is structured as the following:

```
var works = [
{title:"XYZ", img:"portfolio_1"},
{title:"XYZ", img:"portfolio_2"},
{title:"XYZ", img:"portfolio_3"}]

function WorkListController($scope){
                    $scope.works = works;
}

<div class="portfolio" ng-controller="WorkListController">
                <ul class="t1">
                    <li ng-repeat="work in works"><img ng-src='/imgs/{{work.img}}.jpg'>{{work.title}}</li>
                </ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Images from local folder you need to put your project on http server like Apache Tomcat.

Create your project and put your project in webapps folder of tomcat and then start your server. It will deploy application on http server then you can access file with relative path.

Otherwise if you just open your page on browser directly you have to provide full path of your local folder.